# More than one JMS ConnectionFactory

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, jms-topic

I am new to JMS and currently developing a simple Chat application explained in Oreilly 'Java Message service'. I've configured a TopicConnectionFactory in ActiveMQ that receives chat messages from TopicPublishers and dispatch that to TopicSubscribers.

My question is 'why do we need to create more than one TopicConnectionFactory' in any JMS application? Since Connectionfactory instances are not tied up with a Topic/Queue, why can't we use one instance of ConnectionFactory for creating connections to all the Topics (or Queues) configured in an application?

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking you are right. You may be able just to use one ConnectionFactory.

However it is a better design to use multiple ConnectionFactories depending on your requirements so the traffic would be spread out evenly and you do not run out of connections.

So if you know about a JMS Client application that may be problematic (the logic does not allow proper connection handling open/close), you may isolate it to use its own connection factory.

Also some connection factories allow a pool of 10 default active connections at the same time (it depends on the implementation/ settings) if you will need more you may use more than one connection factory.

Answer (score 1):

> I've configured a TopicConnectionFactory in ActiveMQ that receives chat messages from TopicPublishers and dispatch that to TopicSubscribers.

Very ambiguous statement. `TopicConnectionFactory` does not receive or send any messages. It is just one of the admin Objects used to create `Connection` which in turn creates `Session` which in turn creates your publishers and subscribers which publish and subscribe the messages.

> why can't we use one instance of ConnectionFactory for creating connections to all the Topics (or Queues) configured in an application?

You definitely can. There is no one stopping you from doing that.

As per specs

> A connection factory object encapsulates a set of connection configuration 
>   parameters that has been defined by an administrator. A client uses it to 
>   create a connection with a JMS provider.

So unless you have different configuration requirements you can use same `ConnectionFactory` to create multiple Connections. And yes as otc has mentioned above number of connections is one of the configuration parameter.